# Decompression of uploaded file with: The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Im uploading zip file (compressed with winrar) to my server by FileUpload control. On the server I use this code to  decompress file:

```
HttpPostedFile myFile = FileUploader.PostedFile;

            using (Stream inFile = myFile.InputStream)
            {
                using (GZipStream decompress = new GZipStream(inFile, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(decompress);
                    string text = reader.ReadToEnd(); // Here is an error
                }
            }
```

But I get error:

The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream

Is there any way to repair this ? Im using .net 2.0

Thank You very much for help

Comment: How on earth do you expect to decompress a ZIP file with GZip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZIP and GZIP are not quite the same. You can use a third-party library like [#ziplib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) to decompress ZIP files.

Answer (score 3):

GZip is a format that compresses a given stream into another stream. When used with files it is conventionally given the `.gz` extension and the content-type `application/x-gzip` (though often we use the content type of the contained stream and another means of indicating that it's g-zipped). On the web it's often used as a content-encoding or (alas less well-supported given its closer to what we generally really want) transfer-encoding to reduce download and upload time "invisibly" (the user thinks they're downloading a large HTML page but really their downloading a smaller GZip of it).

Zip is a format that compresses an archive of one or more files, along with information about relative paths. The file produced is conventionally given the `.zip` extension, and the content-type `application/zip` (registered with IANA).

There are definite similarities aside from the name, as in they both (generally) use the DEFLATE algorithm, and we can combine the use of GZip with the use of Tar to create an archive similar to what Zip gives us, but they have different uses.

You've got two options:

The simplest (from the programming side of things anyway) is to get a windows tool that produces GZip files (Winrar will open but not create them, but there are dozens of tools that will create them including quite a few that are free). Then your code will work.

The other is to use the [Package Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package.aspx). It's a bit more complicated to use, because a package of potentially several files is inherently more complicated than a single file, but not dreadful by any means. This will let you examine a Zip file, extract the file(s) contained, make changes to them, etc.